# Overriding data\Source::read() and using item() gives me incorrect results

Tags: php, datasource, lithium

I'm trying to override `lithium\data\source\Http::read()` by following [Creating Data Sources](http://li3.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/creating-data-sources.md). This is a result of my problem in [How do I submit POST for cURL in Lithium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295813/how-do-i-submit-post-for-curl-in-lithium).

I now have something like this:

```
<?php

namespace li3_tr42Auth\extensions\adapter\data\source\http;

class TR42 extends \lithium\data\source\Http {

    protected $_classes = [
        // unlike in the "Creating Data Sources" doc, I had to add the 'schema' key
        // or I get an error when 'Libraries' tries to instantiate it.
        'schema'  => 'lithium\data\DocumentSchema',
        'service' => 'lithium\net\http\Service',
        'entity'  => 'lithium\data\entity\Document',
        'set'     => 'lithium\data\collection\DocumentSet'
    ];

    public function read($query, array $options = []) {
        $params = $query->export($this, ['keys' => ['source', 'conditions']]);
        $source = Inflector::camelize($params['source']);
        $model = Libraries::locate('models', $source);
        .
        .
        .
        $decoded = $this->decode($response);
        /** at this point, $decoded contains an associative array like:
         * Array(
         *     [id] => 42,
         *     [name] => Housni,
         *     [status] => 1,
         *     [country] => Colombo, Sri Lanka
         * )
         */
        return $model::create($decoded, ['exists' => true]);
    }
}
?>
```

If I don't use `item()`, any finder will return the array as it is.
If I do use `item()`, I only get the first value of the array which would be `42`, in this case.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
It turns out that only a `find('first')` causes the above problem.
Using `find('all')` returns an object, as expected.
Not quite sure how to fix this.

**UPDATE #2**
I updated the `read()` code above with the new return code.
If I display the results before returning from `read()`, I see a a proper `Document` object. It looks like something is happening in the `find()` method. Btw, I'm not running any filters for the model. Any idea how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1):

`item()` doesn't exist [anymore](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/pull/970).
You just have to replace this line by `YourModel::create($decoded, ['exists' => true]);`

Pls open an issue in the manual repo to update this part of the docs ;-)

Comment: That's definitely a lot cleaner. I didn't realize the exclusion of `item()` because I forgot to pull from my lithium submodule :/

However, the problem still exists. I still get the first value of an array when I use `find('first')` (instead of getting the first array itself and `find('all')` works fine.

I'll go ahead and make that ticket in a bit :)

Comment: I updated my code so that `$_classes['schema']` contains `lithium\data\DocumentSchema` instead of `lithium\data\Schema`.

Comment: Should be Ok by now ;-)

Comment: The only way I could get this to work is by making `$decoded` an array of arrays: `return $model::create([$decoded], ['exists' => true]);`